# Show Alert from JQuery based on server side method return

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have to call a server side method `GetMSG` using jQuery and that server side method

```
[WebMethod()]
public string GetMSG() {
    if(condition) {
        return 'MSG'
    } else {
        return ''  
    }
}
```

Now using that `msg`I have to show alert. How to use return `msg` and display alert in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the jQuery code to perform the Ajax call and display the return? If yes you could go with something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlOfThePage + "GetMSG",
    type: "get",
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
```

Comment: what is JqXHR in the arguments?could u please elaborate these argument of function

Comment: Official jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR. It allows you to interact with the HTTP request & response. In your case you don't need it but I advise you to read the documentation, there is a lot to learn.